# Where can we find a kotlin naming-convention that include control's naming?

Tags: kotlin, controls, naming-conventions

Where can we find the official naming conventions for Kotlin that includes all the control names? Is it the same as Java?

I've been looking for Java and Kotlin naming conventions, but there seems no official naming conventions for controls in Kotlin.

Comment: Did you check this out [Coding Convention](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coding-conventions.html#naming-rules) ?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but yes I did. I have found almost everything I needed except for the controls... I Think that I will simply follow the control prefixes from Microsoft and adapt the following part according to This Coding Convention.

Comment: Hey, can you help me out understanding what control names are?

Comment: What i call 'control name' are 'btn' for button, 'lbl' for label, 'txt' for textbox... Here is a link that I've found: https://gist.github.com/hosuaby/fe180dc02238c16e6be2